# Apple tvOS Javascript stop Video AutoPlay upon selection

Tags: tvos

Using MenuBar template and have menu working. However, say you hover over a top level menu items like videos. The Video page automatically loads within the presentation area. BUT when you go to select a video it begins to autoplay before a user click thus inhibiting users from selecting other videos but the first video. I simply want the videos not to autoplay and await an input from the user. I tried an eventListener but it was ignored. I am at a loss of what to do.

Presenter.js

```
    var Presenter = {
    defaultPresenter: function(xml) {
        if(this.loadingIndicatorVisible) {
            navigationDocument.replaceDocument(xml, this.loadingIndicator);
            this.loadingIndicatorVisible = false;
        } else {
            navigationDocument.pushDocument(xml);
        }
    },

    modalDialogPresenter: function(xml) {
        navigationDocument.presentModal(xml);
    },

    menuBarItemPresenter: function(xml, ele) {
        var feature = ele.parentNode.getFeature("MenuBarDocument");

        if (feature) {
            var currentDoc = feature.getDocument(ele);
            if (!currentDoc) {
                feature.setDocument(xml, ele);
            }
        }
    },

    load: function(event) {
        console.log(event);

        var self = this,
            ele = event.target,
            templateURL = ele.getAttribute("template"),
            presentation = ele.getAttribute("presentation");
            videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL");

        if(videoURL) {
            var player = new Player();
            var playlist = new Playlist();
            var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);

            player.playlist = playlist;
            player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
            player.present();
        }

        if (templateURL) {
            self.showLoadingIndicator(presentation);
            resourceLoader.loadResource(templateURL,
                function(resource) {
                    if (resource) {
                        var doc = self.makeDocument(resource);
                        doc.addEventListener("select", self.load.bind(self));
                        doc.addEventListener("highlight", self.load.bind(self));

                        if (self[presentation] instanceof Function) {
                            self[presentation].call(self, doc, ele);
                        } else {
                            self.defaultPresenter.call(self, doc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    },

    makeDocument: function(resource) {
        if (!Presenter.parser) {
            Presenter.parser = new DOMParser();
        }

        var doc = Presenter.parser.parseFromString(resource, "application/xml");
        return doc;
    },

    showLoadingIndicator: function(presentation) {
        if (!this.loadingIndicator) {
            this.loadingIndicator = this.makeDocument(this.loadingTemplate);
        }

        if (!this.loadingIndicatorVisible && presentation != "modalDialogPresenter" && presentation != "menuBarItemPresenter") {
            navigationDocument.pushDocument(this.loadingIndicator);
            this.loadingIndicatorVisible = true;
        }
    },

    removeLoadingIndicator: function() {
        if (this.loadingIndicatorVisible) {
            navigationDocument.removeDocument(this.loadingIndicator);
            this.loadingIndicatorVisible = false;
        }
    },

    loadingTemplate: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <document>
          <loadingTemplate>
            <activityIndicator>
              <text>Loading...</text>
            </activityIndicator>
          </loadingTemplate>
        </document>`
}
```

--- application.js ---

```
var resourceLoader;
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
    var javascriptFiles = [
        `${options.BASEURL}js/ResourceLoader.js`,
        `${options.BASEURL}js/Presenter.js`
    ];
    evaluateScripts(javascriptFiles, function(success) {
        if (success) {
            resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader(options.BASEURL);
            var index = resourceLoader.loadResource(`${options.BASEURL}templates/CalvaryTVMenuBar.xml.js`, 
                function(resource) {
                    var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
                    doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
                    navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
                });
        } else {
            var alert = createAlert("Evaluate Scripts Error", "There was an error attempting to evaluate the external JavaScript files.\n\n Please check your network connection and try again later.");
            navigationDocument.presentModal(alert);
            throw ("Playback Example: unable to evaluate scripts.");
        }
    });
}

var createAlert = function(title, description) {  
    var alertString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <document>
          <alertTemplate>
            <title>${title}</title>
            <description>${description}</description>
          </alertTemplate>
        </document>`
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var alertDoc = parser.parseFromString(alertString, "application/xml");
    return alertDoc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Josh**,

Try removing the highlight event that you are attaching while loading the document using resourceLoader.loadResource method.

It seems, you are attaching both the events

1. doc.addEventListener("select", self.load.bind(self));
2. doc.addEventListener("highlight", self.load.bind(self));

Try removing the second one.

Comment: Thank you Hari. Thank you! I have it working. LOL, I was so frustrated. THANK YOU!